# Excluding rows in a SQL query based on values in another row while preserving multiple outputs of a single part ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, capability

I have machine output data in the form:

```
DATETIME            ID       VALUE
8-28-20 20:55:10    part1    13
8-28-20 20:56:60    part1    20
8-28-20 20:57:22    part1    25
8-28-20 20:59:39    part2    9
8-28-20 21:10:55    part3    33
8-28-20 21:14:30    part1    14
```

and I need to generate a new table by removing some rows:

```
DATETIME            ID       VALUE
8-28-20 20:57:22    part1    25
8-28-20 20:59:39    part2    9
8-28-20 21:10:55    part3    33
8-28-20 21:14:30    part1    14
```

The machine sometimes collects multiple VALUEs for each run, but I only need the last one (it's cumulative). However, I may have multiple runs of the same ID per shift, and it's not impossible to have 2 consecutive runs of the same ID.

Is it possible with SQL to filter out all rows where ID of a row is equal to the ID of the row above it, only if the VALUE is greater than the VALUE of the row above it?

There's some similar Qs posted here but they all result in grouping rows and taking a max value, but then I'd only capture one run per ID for each time period.

Comment: What is your desired output? Can you please post the sample output?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I just want to generate a new table that excludes the "bad" data so I can create some visualizations from it. I was able to do it trivially in Excel with some helper columns, but if I can find a way to do it with a single SQL statement, I can generate live visualizations instead of needing to manually dump data in excel first.

Comment: provide your expected output in table format

Comment: I edited the main post with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the rows where the `id` changes and the value increases:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(id) over (order by datetime) as next_id,
             lead(value) over (order by datetime) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
where next_id is null or next_id <> id or
      (next_id = id and next_value < value)
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more generic, and also as an example to get a session id without a specific OLAP function for that:

```
WITH
-- your input
input(dttm,id,value) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 20:55:10','part1',13
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 20:56:60','part1',20
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 20:57:22','part1',25
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 20:59:39','part2',9
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 21:10:55','part3',33
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 21:14:30','part1',14
)
,
-- add a counter that is at 1 whenever the id changes over time
with_chg AS (
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN LAG(id) OVER(ORDER BY dttm) <> id THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS chg_count
  , *
  FROM input
)
,
-- use the running sum of that change counter to get a session id
with_session AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(chg_count) OVER(ORDER BY dttm) AS session_id
  , dttm
  , id
  , value
  FROM with_chg
)
,
-- partition by the session id, order by datetime descending to get
-- the row number of 1 for the right row
with_rownum AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY dttm DESC) AS rownum
  , dttm
  , id
  , value
  FROM with_session
)
-- finally, filter by row number 1 and order back by datetime
SELECT
  dttm
, id
, value
FROM with_rownum
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY 1
;
-- out         dttm         |  id   | value 
-- out ---------------------+-------+-------
-- out  2020-08-28 20:57:22 | part1 |    25
-- out  2020-08-28 20:59:39 | part2 |     9
-- out  2020-08-28 21:10:55 | part3 |    33
-- out  2020-08-28 21:14:30 | part1 |    14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, 
       row_number() over(partition by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DATETIME), 0), id order by DATETIME desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: I think you want `order by [datetime] desc` rather than `value`.

Comment: @klacca . . . This happens to work on the data you specified but it does not implement the rules explained in the question.  It returns one row per id per hour.